# Can I use find and grep in one line?

Tags: grep, find

I have a directory structure based on events.

In these events, I have one type of file which does or does not contain a pattern for which I need to search. The positive results I would like to store in a separate file.

My first approach was:

```
find . /EVENT*/'filename' | grep 'searchtext' head -2 > error_file
```

but that does not seem to work. I was told that it is not possible to combine `find` and `grep` in this way, so how do I need to do it?

Comment: Note that what you are doing here is (*approximately*; this is not technically 100% correct, but it's close enough for a first order approximation to give you an idea what's actually going on) first run `find . /EVENT*/'filename'`, then take whatever that command prints on its standard output (which in the case of `find` by default will be a list of file names) and pass *that* as standard input into the command `grep 'searchtext' head -2` (which doesn't make a lot of sense as `grep` won't look at stdin when given file names), then redirect standard output of `grep` into the file `error_file`.

Comment: If I interpret it correctly, it looks like there is a glob-like expansion in `/EVENT*/'filename'`. I'm not sure how to do this with `find`, and AFAIK `bash` cannot do this. All the answers so far have missed this.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a general pattern:

```
find /directory/containing/files -type f -exec grep -H 'pattern_to_search' {} +
```

Here at first `find` will search all files in the directory containing necessary files, you can also use wildcards e.g. `*.txt` to look for only files ending with `.txt`. In that case the command would be:

```
find /directory/containing/files -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -H 'pattern_to_search' {} +
```

After finding the necessary files we are searching for the desired pattern in those files using `-exec grep -H 'pattern_to_search' {} +` (`-H` will print the filename where the pattern is found). Here you can think of `{}` as containing the files to be searched and `+` is needed to be used at the end with `-exec` so that `-exec` will be forked only once i.e. `grep` will search as if the command is `grep -H 'pattern_to_search' file_1.txt file_2.txt file_3.txt`.

Comment: Okay -- I guess this is the reason: http://superuser.com/questions/140689/why-does-using-dev-null-in-find-grep-display-the-file-name If there ends up being only one file in the match, grep won't print the file name, so adding `/dev/null` ensures there's at least two if there's a match.  But using `-H` seems a more normative, less zany-hack style method (and less typing).  I'd change it to that ;)

Comment: I also think you need `'{}'`, not plain `{}`.  Otherwise I get `missing argument to -exec`.

Comment: @goldilocks - you shouldn't have to quote that.

Comment: @mikeserv  Hmmmph, looks like it is a **fish** shell issue -- exact same thing under bash is fine.  I remember getting confused about this a while back, I guess it was when I starting using fish as my default.

Comment: I'd also go for single quotes rather than doubles, ski as to avoid any unexpected interpolations

Comment: @Jos This answer is how I think you'll typically want to proceed. Once find has a match, you want to Execute the grep search, or some other command, using the "-exec"

Answer (score 5):

Another valid method is:

```
 find /directory/containing/files -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "test to search"
```

The print0 / option -0 is to allow for the case where filename strings contain special characters (like spaces).

Comment: Using `-exec grep "test to search" {} +` handles filenames with special characters just fine. The only reason not to use it is that some systems do not support it.

Answer (score 2):

And one more way, in just a single process (without `find`, `-exec`, `xargs`):

```
grep -r "test to search" /directory/containing/files
```

Well, with GNU grep, anyway. :)

ETA: Since I've been asked to show the `grep --include` option, here's an analogue to heemayl's example ("you can also use wildcards e.g. *.txt to look for only files ending with .txt"):

```
grep --include '*.txt*' -r "pattern to search" /directory/containing/files
```

And while I'm editing, yes, these are alternatives, not drop-in replacements: These commands will read (regular) files through symlinks.  (They won't recurse through symlinked directories though; for that you need `-R`.)  They will also read sockets, named pipes, and device files (though `-D skip` can be added to, um, skip those).  And there's no way with `grep` to get the effect of `find` options like `-mtime -2`.  If you need those – use `find`.  If you don't, well, I'd argue `grep` is a nice alternative.

Comment: This is different in that grep then searches *all* files (which is sometimes not fun) rather than those matching a `find` pattern.

Comment: @goldilocks Sure, if you _have_ a `find` pattern.  Except, you can give patterns to `grep -r` as well; most commonly `--exclude=GLOB` (or `--include=GLOB`) and `--exclude-dir=GLOB`, though I guess you sometimes need `-D skip` and/or `-I`.  But sure, if you have `-mtime -2` or somesuch, you need that `find`.  `grep -r` is another option, not a replacement.

Comment: @The Sidhekin: you should edit your post to add the --include option. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @jopasserat Really? What to `--include` though?  The original does-not-work approach didn't specify any.  Though I guess I could add an analogue to heemayl's can-also-use example …

Comment: Well considering OP's question, he seems to have a particular type of files to search in. So I'd say --include='pattern' with pattern matching whatever he wants.

Answer (score -1):

I will assume that you need to grep for a particular pattern through text files and recurse through subdirectories. If you are using GNU grep, it is pretty simple:

```
cd /to/the/top/level    
grep -r "PatternToSearch" *
```

Instead of `-r`, you can use `-R` or `--recursive`

You must use quotes if you have spaces in your search pattern.

There are a lot of options to GNU grep. Just type in `grep --help` and you will be amazed !

Comment: How do you ask grep to look at only files that match a particular patter?  Say, filename extension?   This proposal will make grep look in every file in the file system under this folder: that's not what the question is trying to do.

Comment: Something like *.log should do. By the way, the Silver Searcher would be more handy and faster for this:
`ag SearchWord FilePattern`